# how to add an extension method

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, repository, repository-pattern

[image]Firstly I am calling getall() method in various controller methods and then using linq query to get only active users. But I want to make a generic function which get all the active propoties from various tables at once. So that I can only call that specific "getallwhere" method.

```
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllWhere(TEntity entity)
    {

        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(c=>c.isActive == true)
    }



public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllWhere();


}`
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working?

Comment: I've always disliked expression trees, but what is the exact issue?

Comment: var category = _categoryRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.IsActive == true) but I want something like this :- var category = _categoryRepository.GetAllWhere();

Comment: everything is working fine. the problem is first I get all fields and then apply where condition. I want to make a specific function to perform this task and then call that function everywhere.

Comment: To reiterate, I believe you want to pass an expression from another layer to your entity context where the compiler will still automatically build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for extension methods like:

```
public static class RepositoryExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllWhere(this Repository repository)
    {
        return repository.GetAll().Where(x => x.isActive);
    }
}
```

To create an extension method you have to declare a static class and define a static method which takes a this as the first parameter.

You can then use your method as if it was present in the original type.

```
myRepository.GetAllWhere();
```

You can check the doc [ExtensionMethods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Comment: is it possible to achieve this in the existing class(please see the screenshot I have posted)??

Comment: the beauty with extension method is you can put it beside your class and it will work as if it was inside the class (that's why it's called extension)

Comment: I did not know about extension methods. now I will look at it. thanks for the tip

Comment: Not to nit pick, but for the love of everything good and holy, name this something like `GetAllActive`. Using a name like `GetAllWhere` is just a good way to make the next developer who inherits this code want to beat you in the face with a shovel.

Comment: Yeah, I was just responding to original poster specifications :)